# AWS VPN: Can't ping customer side with EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, vpc

I have an AWS VPN set up, with the tunnel status "UP". However, I am not able to ping anything on my customer's side, and they are not able to ping my EC2 instance.

Customer side has internal IPs that I need to connect to: 192.168.yy.yy1, 192.168.yy.yy2

My VPC has CIDR block of 10.0.0.0/16

My EC2 instance is set up on 10.0.1.161

For the VPN Tunnel: Inside IP CIDR 169.254.xx.26/30

Static routes: 192.168.yy.yy1/32 192.168.yy.yy2/32

Route table entries for the VPC (IGW = Internet Gateway, VGW = Virtual Gateway):

```
Destination       | Target   | Status | Propagated
10.0.0.0/16       | local    | Active | No
0.0.0.0/0         | IGW      | Active | No
192.168.yy.yy1/32 | VGW      | Active | Yes
192.168.yy.yy2/32 | VGW      | Active | Yes
```

I'm only using one subnet on the VPC: 10.0.1.0/24

traceroute as below

```
traceroute to 192.168.yy.yy1/32 (192.168.yy.yy1/32), 30 hops max, 
60 byte packets
1  100.96.2.1 (100.96.2.1)  0.035 ms  0.019 ms  0.015 ms
2  * * *
3  * * *
4  * * *
5  * * *
6  * * *
7  * * *
8  * * *
9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
```

Why i am not able to ping the server?

Comment: Is ICMP allowed in your security group? any firewall rules on the customer side?

Comment: yes ICMP is enabled both the ends

Comment: Aside from using ping, have you tried any connectivity? For example, ssh into an EC2 instance? I ask this because these types of connections are obviously your end-goal, rather than getting ping working. Which type of [VPN Connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html) are you using?

Comment: Is your subnet where your 10.0.1.161 instance lives associated with your route table?

Comment: yes subnet is associated with route table @programmerj

Comment: Do you have a route table from the customer side?